# Delete python .exe's cwd

Tags: python, delete-directory

I'm trying to make a uninstaller tool and I'm having issues with the end of the code

This works but only deletes the .exe not the cwd

```
subprocess.Popen(f"WAITFOR /T 2 PAUSE 2>NUL & DEL \"{argv[0]}\" /f", shell=True, creationflags=0x00000008)
```

This deletes everything in the directory but not the directory itself

```
subprocess.Popen(f"WAITFOR /T 2 PAUSE 2>NUL & RD /Q /S \"{os.getcwd()}\"", shell=True, creationflags=0x00000008)
```

Comment: I don't think you can delete the directory while inside it. Try changing the current working directory to parent and then deleting the directory.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
os.chdir("..")
subprocess.Popen(f"(WAITFOR /T 5 PAUSE 2>NUL) & (RD /Q /S \"{os.getcwd()}\\FolderToDelete\")", shell=True, creationflags=0x00000008)
```

Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/users/1362735/heretolearn